# Passagem de Parâmetros em ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Tenho o seguinte código:

**Página Administrador**:

```
private void Salvar()
{
    Session.Add("Salvar", txtSobre.Text);
    try
    {
        if (txtSobre.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            Session["Salvar"] = txtSobre.Text.Trim();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}

protected void btnSobre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Salvar();
}
```

**Página Usuário**:

```
private void Atualizar()
{
    try
    {
        lblSobre.Text = Session["Salvar"].ToString();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}

protected void btnAtualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Atualizar();
}
```

E não estou conseguindo passar um texto do `TextBox` para a label da outra página. Dá o seguinte erro:

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Comment: Primeiramente verifique se as diretivas, se não me engano a diretiva correta é System.Web.UI. Também tente debugar, coloque um ponto de interrupção exatamente na linha que está recebendo o valor da Session, posicione o mouse acima da session e verifique se o valor que ele está recebendo é o desejado.

Comment: É importante você tratar esse dado, principalmente por que ele vem por sessão. No que postou na pergunta não há problema, você tem que avaliar se a sessão está sendo perdida/limpada na sua aplicação por algum motivo ao carregar a página de usuário.

Comment: @MaisaBerlofa Veja minha resposta e confirme se era esse mesmo, o seu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro acontece porque você está tentando acessar uma chave de sessão que não foi declarada... para evitar o erro você pode simplesmente verificar se ela existe antes de fazer a atribuição.

```
private void Atualizar()
{
    try
    {
        lblSobre.Text = Session["Salvar"]?.ToString();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}

protected void btnAtualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Atualizar();
}
```

Com a alteração acima adicionando a `?` em `Session["Salvar"]?.ToString();` você não receberá mais a mensagem de erro, contudo não irá exibir nenhum valor na TextBox até que seja atribuído algum valor para essa variável na sessão.

E aqui, me parece que você está confundindo algumas coisas... se o acesso à página do administrador e a do usuário é feito com usuários, instâncias ou locais diferentes, ambos não compartilham a mesma sessão.

Não adiantará você adicionar a chave `"Salvar"` na sessão do admin e esperar que ela exista no acesso de um outro usuário. Se você quer que essa variável esteja disponível  para todo mundo você utilizar uma variável de `Application`, porém essa apresentará o mesmo valor para todos os usuários do seu site e será redefinida toda vez que o pool for reciclado ou sua aplicação for reiniciada.

**Página do Administrador**

```
private void Salvar()
{
    try
    {
        if (txtSobre.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            Application["Salvar"] = txtSobre.Text.Trim();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}

protected void btnSobre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Salvar();
}
```

**Página do usuário**

```
private void Atualizar()
{
    try
    {
        lblSobre.Text = Application["Salvar"]?.ToString();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}

protected void btnAtualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Atualizar();
}
```